# From a group of 20 hunters, 5 hit a target with probability 4/5, 7 with probability 3/5 and 8 with probability 1/2.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

From a group of 20 hunters, 5 hit a target with probability 4/5,  7 with probability 3/5 and 8 with probability 1/2.  A hunter taken at random shoots, without hitting the target. Which is the probability that he belongs to the first group ? Can someone explain me how to find this probability ? Thank you.

Comment: ~Bayes theorem~

Comment: Let $M$ be the event the hunter misses, and let $F$ be the event the hunter belongs to the first group. We want $\Pr(F\mid M)$. By the definition of conditional probability, this is $\Pr(F\cap M)/\Pr(M)$. Now you have to compute two probabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $M:=\text{no hit}$ and $F:=\text{belongs to first group}$ then:

$$P(F\mid M)P(M)=P(F\cap M)=P(M\mid F)P(F)$$

Find $P(M),P(M\mid F)$ and $P(F)$ and then use this equality to find $P(F\mid M)$.